# Perl: printing a message to filehandle in END block

Tags: perl, file, exit

I am using a filehandle to print some message to a log file.

I do see some log messages but in a particular if-else block, I have an `exit(1)`.
It then executes the END block, wherein I want to print the timestamp using the Filehandle I opened in the BEGIN block.

But, it seems I lose access to that filehandle because of exit(1) in if block and I get the error message:

```
print() on closed filehandle
```

Any suggestions, how can I capture the timestamp in this case?

Comment: show some code; what kind of filehandle is it?  if it is stored in a variable, show at least from the declaration to the open

Comment: Open the file again in the `END` block.

Comment: mob, does perl automatically close a filehandle when it hits an exit(1)? In that case it makes sense to open the filehandle again and print the log message. I tried doing it that way and it works, so just wanted to clarify

Comment: @iDev: no, it does not.  you've got some other problem.

Comment: Not necessarily (maybe another `END` block is closing your log file?). I don't know anyone that regularly checks the return value of `print`, but it seems like a particularly good idea in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to program more defensively for `END` blocks, where some things (filehandles and other resources that interact with the system, objects with destructors) may not work correctly. The [`${^GLOBAL_PHASE}`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#GLOBAL_PHASE) variable, or for Perls older than v5.14.0, the [`Devel::GlobalDestruction`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aGlobalDestruction) module can help with this:

```
use Devel::GlobalDestruction;

sub my_log_function {
    ...
    my $msg = add_timestamp_to_message(@msg);
    if (! print $loghandle $msg) {
        # who ever checks the return value of print? 
        if (in_global_destruction) {
            # oh, maybe that explains it
            open $loghandle, '>>', $the_log_file;
            print $loghandle $msg;
            close $loghandle;
        }
    }
}
```